# I am having trouble with passing a parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters

I have stored the (num1) and (num2) vairables earlier and i am trying to display the results in a prompt box after but cant get it too work, i have only started learning javascript and help would be appreciated

```
 function calculateNums = (num1 + num2);
                numResult(calculateNums);

            alert("The sum of " +numResult);
```

Comment: Please check your syntax

Comment: Um... Maybe start with a tutorial?

Comment: Here's a good starting point on functions ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is all wrong. Here's how this should look:

```js
var num1 = 4;
var num2 = 7;

function calculateNums(in1, in2) {
    return in1 + in2;
}

var numResult = calculateNums(num1, num2);

alert("The sum of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is " + numResult);
```